# Meteor MongoDB subscription delivering data in 10 second intervals instead of live

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

I believe this is more of a MongoDB question than a Meteor question, so don't get scared if you know a lot about mongo but nothing about meteor.

Running Meteor in development mode, but connecting it to an external Mongo instance instead of using Meteor's bundled one, results in the same problem. This leads me to believe this is a Mongo problem, not a Meteor problem.

---

## The actual problem

I have a [meteor](https://www.meteor.com/) project which continuosly gets data added to the database, and displays them live in the application. It works perfectly in development mode, but has strange behaviour when built and deployed to production. It works as follows:

- A tiny script running separately collects broadcast UDP packages and shoves them into a mongo collection
- The Meteor application then publishes a subset of this collection so the client can use it
- The client subscribes and live-updates its view

The problem here is that the subscription appears to only get data about every 10 seconds, while these UDP packages arrive and gets shoved into the database several times per second. This makes the application behave weird

It is most noticeable on the collection of UDP messages, but not limited to it. It happens with every collection which is subscribed to, even those not populated by the external script

Querying the database directly, either through the mongo shell or through the application, shows that the documents are indeed added and updated as they are supposed to. The publication just fails to notice and appears to default to querying on a 10 second interval

Meteor uses oplog tailing on the MongoDB to find out when documents are added/updated/removed and update the publications based on this

Anyone with a bit more Mongo experience than me who might have a clue about what the problem is?

---

For reference, this is the dead simple publication function

```
/**
 * Publishes a custom part of the collection. See {@link  https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-find} for args
 *
 * @returns {Mongo.Cursor}      A cursor to the collection
 *
 * @private
 */
function custom(selector = {}, options = {}) {
        return udps.find(selector, options);
}
```

and the code subscribing to it:

```
Tracker.autorun(() => {
        // Params for the subscription
        const selector = {
                "receivedOn.port": port
        };
        const options = {
                limit,
                sort: {"receivedOn.date": -1},
                fields: {
                        "receivedOn.port": 1,
                        "receivedOn.date": 1
                }
        };

        // Make the subscription
        const subscription = Meteor.subscribe("udps", selector, options);

        // Get the messages
        const messages = udps.find(selector, options).fetch();

        doStuffWith(messages); // Not actual code. Just for demonstration
});
```

---

Versions:

Development:

- node 8.9.3
- mongo 3.2.15

Production:

- node 8.6.0
- mongo 3.4.10

Comment: Please confirm you are using oplog. 10 seconds is a default rate for polling.

Comment: @AlexBlex Unless it's on by default, I'm apparently not... I noticed Meteor has a MONGO_OPLOG_URL environment variable. I tried setting it to the same as my MONGO_URL, but that givers the error message `Error: $MONGO_OPLOG_URL must be set to the 'local' database of a Mongo replica set`. I guess the question now becomes "How do I use oplog tailing on a MongoDB?"

Comment: Found this: https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/setting-up-mongodb-oplog-tailing# Unless someone beats me to it, I will post an answer when I get it working

Comment: Are you using a single server for database ?

Comment: @BadisMerabet Yes

Comment: I will prepare an answer for you in few minutes to consider about how meteor provide real time on top of mongodb that doesn’t have any built-in real time features.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Meteor use two modes of operation to provide real time on top of mongodb that doesn’t have any built-in real time features. **poll-and-diff** and **oplog-tailing**

1 - **Oplog-tailing**

It works by reading the mongo database’s replication log that it uses to synchronize secondary databases (the ‘oplog’). This allows Meteor to deliver realtime updates across multiple hosts and scale horizontally.
It's more complicated, and provides real-time updates across multiple servers.

2 - **Poll and diff**

The poll-and-diff driver works by repeatedly running your query (polling) and computing the difference between new and old results (diffing). The server will re-run the query every time another client on the same server does a write that could affect the results. It will also re-run periodically to pick up changes from other servers or external processes modifying the database. Thus poll-and-diff can deliver realtime results for clients connected to the same server, but it introduces noticeable lag for external writes. 
(*the default is 10 seconds, and this is what you are experiencing , see attached image also* ).

[image]
[image]

This may or may not be detrimental to the application UX, depending on the application (eg, bad for chat, fine for todos).

This approach is simple and and delivers easy to understand scaling characteristics. However, it does not scale well with lots of users and lots of data. Because each change causes all results to be refetched, CPU time and network bandwidth scale O(N²) with users. Meteor automatically de-duplicates identical queries, though, so if each user does the same query the results can be shared.

You can tune poll-and-diff by changing values of `pollingIntervalMs` and `pollingThrottleMs`.

You have to use `disableOplog: true` option to opt-out of oplog tailing on a per query basis.

```
Meteor.publish("udpsPub", function (selector) {
  return udps.find(selector, {
    disableOplog: true,
    pollingThrottleMs: 10000, 
    pollingIntervalMs: 10000
  });
});
```

Additional links:

https://medium.baqend.com/real-time-databases-explained-why-meteor-rethinkdb-parse-and-firebase-dont-scale-822ff87d2f87

https://blog.meteor.com/tuning-meteor-mongo-livedata-for-scalability-13fe9deb8908

[How to use pollingThrottle and pollingInterval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38661193/how-to-use-pollingthrottle-and-pollinginterval)

Comment: This indeed appears to be my problem. Setting `disableOplog: true` and lowering `pollingIntervalMs` makes the data come through much faster. I will still try to get the oplog tailing working, as part of the reason Meteor was selected for the project was its real time capabilities

Comment: Sure, I will provide more links that explain how meteor tools work on top or replace mongodb strategies for real time changes.

Comment: The second image (gif) above explain why you only notice 10 seconds delay on production apps and not on local machine.

Comment: I have now created a replica set and successfully gotten Oplog Tailing to work. The application now live-updates its data, as intended. The following guide was helpful for me in creating the replication set: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/convert-standalone-to-replica-set/

Answer (score 0):

It's a DDP (Websocket ) heartbeat configuration.

Meteor real time communication and live updates is performed using DDP ( JSON based protocol which Meteor had implemented on top of SockJS ).
Client and server where it can change data and react to its changes.

DDP (Websocket) protocol implements so called PING/PONG messages (Heartbeats) to keep Websockets alive. The server sends a PING message to the client through the Websocket, which then replies with PONG.

By default heartbeatInterval is configure at little more than 17 seconds (17500 milliseconds).

Check here: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/d6f0fdfb35989462dcc66b607aa00579fba387f6/packages/ddp-client/common/livedata_connection.js#L54

You can configure heartbeat time in milliseconds on server by using:

```
Meteor.server.options.heartbeatInterval = 30000;
Meteor.server.options.heartbeatTimeout = 30000;
```

Other Link:

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/0963bda60ea5495790f8970cd520314fd9fcee05/packages/ddp/DDP.md#heartbeats

Comment: This doesn't appear to be the cause... I tried lowering it to first 1000, then 100. No difference. It's also exactly 10 seconds, not 17.5, or 15, as my settings originally were

Comment: This also would not explain why it works with Meteor's bundled mongo instance, but not with a standalone mongo server, all other things being the same. The DDP connection does not talk directly to the database

Comment: I have a meteor project on heroku connected to a mongodb on mlab. when i change data manually in mongodb. it waits less than 18 seconds to update data live in my meteor frontend.

Comment: You are right. on my local machine. it updates data instantly.it takes no time. i will check why it's different from production.